# Change tint color of keyboard for UITextField

Tags: objective-c, ios

I would like to set a custom color for the keyboard that is associated with a UITextField. I see that I can set the UIKeyboardAppearanceType, but I would like to be able to set the color to arbitrary color, rather than just change to a different default setting. I was hoping it would be as simple as something like this:

keyboard.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:...]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no public API to access the system keyboard, so you're out of luck without re-writing UIKeyboard from scratch (which is a bad idea), or finding some private API to do the job (which is a bad idea if you want to submit to the App Store).

Comment: Hmmmm. This is what I feared when I couldn't find an answer with a quick Google search. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Alert style keyboard and place a view in the background with a background color of your choice. This will make the keyboard a different color.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode look for the 'Keyboard Look' attribute in the Text Input Traits section of the Attributes Inspector. Can toggle between Light/Dark.

[image]